# Fit content mode for a custom view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I set content mode as fit for a custom `UIImageView` wrapped in SwiftU?

```
struct CustomView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        CustomUIImage()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView()
    }
}
```

In the code above, `CustomUIImage` is a subclass of `UIImageView` from `UIKit`. It's wrapped in `UIViewRepresentable` to integrate it with the SwiftUI framework. Calling `CustomView().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` didn't work in this case

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach

```
struct CustomView: UIViewRepresentable {

    private let imageView = CustomUIImage()

    init(contentMode: UIView.ContentMode = .center) {
        imageView.contentMode = contentMode
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIImageView {
        imageView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIImageView, context: Context) {
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomView(contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried setting content mode on the UIImageView itself but that didn't work

Comment: @pkc13, tested & works with `UIImageView` on Xcode 11.3 / iOS 13.3.